# Spring Data JDBC SQLFeatureNotSupportedException while saving list of enum to MySql

Tags: mysql, spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I've a model named `Role`. A `role` has a list of `Permission`s, simple as that.

Using org.springframework.boot:2.2.5.RELEASE, spring-jdbc version 5.2.24, mysql-connector-java-8.0.19, mysql server version 5.7.28

You can also checkout https://github.com/tirbison/spring-data-jdbc-kotlin/tree/bug/mysql-list-of-enum to reproduce the bug, do not forget to change the mysql credentials.

Role.kt

```
package com.example.demo.domain.model

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

class Role(
        val name: String,
        val permissions: List<Permission> = emptyList()
) {
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null
}

enum class Permission {
    READ, WRITE, EXECUTE
}
```

schema

```
create table role
(
    id          serial primary key,
    name        varchar(256),
    permissions varchar(256)
);
```

I don't have a separate table for permissions simple because **I couldn't find a way to save an `enum` collection to a table using spring-data-jdbc**, it could be a separate table or a column not so important.

When I use `H2` in-memory db I do not get any exceptions, `H2` saves enums to a column in a comma separated form. However when I use MySql I get the following exception stack trace:

```
org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=com.example.demo.domain.model.Role@14292d71, generatedId=null)

    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction.executeWith(DbAction.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.lambda$executeWith$0(AggregateChange.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.executeWith(AggregateChange.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads(DemoApplicationTests.kt:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ConnectionCallback; null; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:96)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:336)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.createArray(DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.writeJdbcValue(BasicJdbcConverter.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.addConvertedPropertyValue(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:423)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.lambda$getParameterSource$1(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.getParameterSource(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultJdbcInterpreter.interpret(DefaultJdbcInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction$InsertRoot.doExecuteWith(DbAction.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction.executeWith(DbAction.java:54)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLFeatureNotSupportedException(SQLError.java:236)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createArrayOf(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcTemplate.java:1525)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.createArrayOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.lambda$createArray$1(DefaultJdbcTypeFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:328)
    ... 114 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC currently supports two variants of persisting lists.

When the content is an entity it gets stored in a separate table.

When the content is a simple typ it gets stored in an array if the database supports this.

Since MySql doesn't support arrays you are stuck with the first variant.
But Enums are simple types (i.e. they can directly stored in a column).

The solution is to wrap the enum in an entity type, i.e. a simple type with a single attribute containing the enum.

Comment: Does spring data jdbc support the use of `float[]` arrays? I get `Unable to find server array type for provided name REAL` even if I try to cast to `float4[]`

Answer (score 0):

One other solution would be making the `permissions` `@Transient` and having a private field to be persisted to the DB

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient

class Role(
        val name: String
) {
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null

    @Transient
    var permissions: List<Permission> = emptyList()
        get() {
            return permissionList.split(",").map { Permission.valueOf(it.trim()) }
        }
        set(value) {
            field = value
            permissionList = value.joinToString()
        }

    private var permissionList: String = ""

}
```

and db schema

```
create table role
(
    id              serial primary key,
    name            varchar(256),
    permission_list varchar(256)
);
```

spring data jdbc will not try to persist `permissions` as it is `@Transient` but will persist `permissionList`.

[permission_list saved as a csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU0m0.png)